# How to load only section of html in a single .md file using react-static-boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs

By using `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />` It will load all the HTML in *index.md* file. Can I create a key so that I can only load part of that html file. Something like `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html.section1 }} />` and `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html.section2 }} />`

**index.js**

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { title, html } from './index.md';

class AboutPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="section1">
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html.section1 }} />
        </div>
        <div className="section2">
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html.section2 }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.md**

```
---
title: About    
---

## Section 1

text about section 1


## Section 2

text about section 2
```

I am using [react-static-boilerplate](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown is just a plain text file, you cannot extract HTML from it unless it explicitly has HTML tags in it.  In your case, it doesn't. You'd need to first parse it to HTML with a parser such as [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) or [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it), and then you'd be able to select the elements that you need.